# Why does my javascript slow down in Safari desktop but not Chrome or Safari mobile?

Tags: javascript, safari

I have a javascript that does a lot of calculations and plots the results in the form of many arrays to Google Charts objects. Without reloading the page, I can apply new values and run the analysis again and again, plotting the results each time. The odd thing is that this works fine in Chrome, but in Safari on macOS it gets slower with each new analysis and requires a reload of the page to get it back up to speed. However in Chrome desktop and mobile and in Safari mobile, it keeps running at top speed, not requiring a reload. I suspect Safari macOS is caching something and filling memory. I am using a bunch of graph objects (code below) that get created each time (but presumably also garbage collected).

```
        var chart01 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_01'));
    var chart02 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_02'));
    var chart03 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_03'));
    var chart04 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_04'));
    var chart05 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_05'));
    var chart06 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_06'));
    var chart07 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_07'));
    var chart08 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_08'));
    var chart09 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_09'));
    var chart10 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_10'));
    var chart11 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_11'));
    var chart12 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_12'));
    var chart13 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_13'));
    var chart14 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_14'));
    var chart15 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_15'));
```

Comment: Try using the memory profiler to see if that's what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally update the charts with new data instead of creating them every time. This is to avoid any kind of garbage collection delays.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried placing the declarations outside the function that adds the data, but I receive an error, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LineChart' of undefined," and the charts do not work. Probably a scoping issue that is beyond my ability to solve. I don't know how to make the chart objects available to the function that assigns the data without making them global, and I think the only alternative is to pass them as arguments, which would be really cumbersome since there are so many.